# Google Sign In Authenticate with a backend server

Tags: java, android, google-oauth

I need to get access token from android app and send it to backend server in order to make some operation with google calendar api.

I followed this:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

But I got com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10
Something gone wrong with "server_client_id"

In https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials I maked two try

1) with client id for webapplication (I am using it in app project web version)

2) with client id for android app reporting the SHA-1 as requested

What is the right way 1 or 2? And why I'm got an error?
Thank you

I'm using the code above:

```
/*GOOGLE OAUTH*/
public void signIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

}


private void handleSignInResult(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String idToken = account.getIdToken();

        Log.v("MYLOG","Ottengo Access Token " + idToken);
        // TODO(developer): send ID Token to server and validate

        //updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w("MYLOG", "handleSignInResult:error", e);
        //updateUI(null);
    }
}
/*GOOGLE OAUTH END*/

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    /*GOOGLE SIGN IN OAUTH SECTION*/
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, and doubts.

1) Don't forget to put credentials.json in your app root directory.

2) If you need a backend server you can use credentials.json (and client_id) from web version (for example the same you're using for your website software version).
Don't needed an android oauth client id with sha1 fingerprint etc.)

3) you can use the same apikey as website, but if you want to make a restriction based on referer (for website) and based on android app.. you have to make two api key, one with referer restriction and one with sha1 fingerprint restriction

hope this help other guys!